# How define multiple indexed fields in model class for mongodb collection in spring-data-mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have model class looking like below, I would like to have indexed fields `id`, `openid` and `unionid`.

However I found only a index field `id` after inserting data in `User` collection.

Is there any way to specify multiple indexed fields in model class via using spring-data-mongodb?

```
public class User {
    @Indexed
    String id;
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    String unionid;
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    String openid;
    String nickname;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned out **CompoundIndex** is capable of my requirement.

```
@CompoundIndexes({ @CompoundIndex(name = "openid", unique = true, background = true, def = "{'openid': 1}"),
        @CompoundIndex(name = "unionid", background = true, def = "{'unionid': 1}") })
```